# Using SUM() in VBA

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

If I have a set of cells in a worksheet that I want to add up, I can use the formula:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!A1:A10)
```

To do this in a sub, I would use:

```
Sub example1()
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant

    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
End Sub
```

If, however, I want to add up a single cell across many worksheets, I use the formula:

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet38!B2)
```

In VBA this line fails miserably, as explained in [Specify an Excel range across sheets in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923028/specify-an-excel-range-across-sheets-in-vba):

```
Sub dural()
    v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("Sheet1:Sheet3!B2")
End Sub
```

I have two workarounds. I can the the sum by programming a loop:

```
Sub example2()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim v As Variant

    v = 0
    For i = 1 To 38
        v = v + Sheets(i).Range("B2")
    Next i
End Sub
```

or by using `Evaluate()`:

```
v = Evaluate("Sum(Sheet1:Sheet3!B2)")
```

Is it possible to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum()` for this calculation, or should I stick the loop?

Comment: Why not `evaluate`?

Comment: I haven't done any of this in a long time, so I won't add this as an answer until you can try it, but shouldn't you need to also use: `Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Sheet1:Sheet3!B2")` and then do `Sum` on `r`? Or similar... whatever you need to do to create a range from the sheets. You're probably better off using one of your other approaches though.

Comment: @findwindow  I do use `Evaluate()` and it works fine....but if I  have to calculate based on a dynamic range *(same on all sheets)*, there is an extra step making the string I must supply to `Evaluate()`

Comment: @gmiley  Thanks for the idea, bit I can't seem to make a Range Object from cells from different sheets.

Comment: You could make a named range that has all the sheet names you want then use this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'" & sheetrng & "'!B2")))`  where sheetrng is the named range.  Obviously you will need to convert it into a string for the Evaluate method.

Comment: @ScottCraner  thank you..........I'll have to think about how to create that Named Range....................

Comment: You can also create two hidden blank sheets "START" and "FINISH" and bookend the sheets you want.  Then `v = Evaluate("Sum(START:FINISH!B2)")`

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank for the suggestion.................It works well since all the data sheets in the workbook are grouped together anyway.

Comment: And as you know, but I will put here for future viewers, you can replace the B2 part with a dynamic range reference.  For example say you have the range you want set as a variable `rng` it would be `v = Evaluate("Sum(START:FINISH!" & rng.Address(1,1) & ")")`

Comment: @ScottCraner  **THAT NAILED IT !!**................it handles both the dynamic range and the variable sheets issue..............THANKS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the issue with the worksheetfunction.sum is that it needs arguments to evaluate not string.  WorksheetFunction.Sum("Sheet1!A1:A3") fails as well.  However, this succeeds

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet1.Range("A1"), Sheet2.Range("A1"))
```

The Ranges could be whatever you like.

Comment: This works but that will only be valid for adding values in two cells but to make the function over a range of cells I used this work around `string rng = "D2:D" + totalRows+1;

            //calculate and return the average/mean as a float with Excel Worksheetfunction
            return (float)app.WorksheetFunction.Average(propertySheet.Range[rng]);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the loop to perform the calculation across all of the sheets, it's the most efficient way by the looks of things. As mentioned above you can type each range separately instead.

Might be worth converting the range your adding up to a double (or single, integer, etc) because sometimes VBA reads numbers as text.

`v = v + Cdbl(Sheets(i).Range("B2"))`

The reason why you're having issues with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("Sheet1:Sheet3!B2")` is because if you type that formula into Excel, the range 'Sheet1:Sheet3!B2' won't be recognised by excel.

[image]

To use a `Application.WorksheetFunction` it has to work in excel outside of VBA.

Hope that helps.

Comment: To be fair, the range in the screenshot has a typo. There's an extra `!` before the colon.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Sub SumWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'    If ws.Name <> ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then ' (Sum other sheets only)
    If ws.Name <> "" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    v = v + ws.Range("B2")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    Next ws
    MsgBox v
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please include some explanation along with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work just by the line:

```
Cells(x,y) = WorksheetFunction.sum(range(a,b:a,d))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a very simple VBA statement:

```
MSC = Range("MyScores")
MyTotal = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(MSC))
```

In the above MyScores is the address range in a cell named "MyScores" Which is the naormal Excel address formula "Address....";  My formula in as follows, but can be changed to whatever is needed I4 holds the specified row.

=ADDRESS(I4,CELL("Col",R9),1)&":"&ADDRESS(J4,CELL("Col",R9),1))
Works perfect for me.