# Excel formula to find max value in range across worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find the max value in a cell over multiple worksheets.  Something like this:

> =MAX(Sheet3:Sheet5!B:B).

The issue is my worksheets are being named dynamically so I pretty much need the formula to go like this:

> =MAX(Sheet3:LastSheet5!B4:B4).

Any ideas on how to do this?  I'm stumped so far.

Comment: You might need to use VBA to achieve what you want.

Comment: what you are looking for a is a 3D max function

Comment: i think you need vba, 3D functions, you need to define your sheet first as the range.

Comment: scott craner recently provided an answer for either Gary's student or BruceWayne I think it was on how to deal with dynamic 3D range.  I just remember part of the answer being place a worksheet named start at the beginning, and a worksheet named finish at the end.  hide both worksheets.  You can then reference 'start:finish'!B4.  The part I cant remember is what formula they were using the reference for as not all formulas will work with 3D referencing.

Comment: Are you always starting at Sheet 3 or is that dynamic too?

Comment: Found [the question on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491625/using-sum-in-vba)...it is indeed a VBA question from Gary's Student.  Have a read and see if it sheds some light on the subject for you.  And feel free to tell me to take a long walk off a short pier if it is misleading information.

Comment: @ForwardEd, you are right, the question from Gary student should helps. After reading the comments there, the trick is to create a hidden sheet and place after sheet 5 and name it "LAST". the formula thus become `=MAX(Sheet3:LAST!B4:B4)`

Comment: The above formula worked.  I needed to do some more complicated manipulation as well though so I just end up making a function in VBA.  Thank you for the help!  It got got me on the right path.