# Sum a range from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get this cell to total a range from another worksheet but I keep getting stuck. The range rows and columns vary but the starting point is always C2. I need to total from C2 to the rest of the used range (aka exclude columns A and B as well as row 1 but include everything else).

Please help if you can.

```
Range("A1").Formula = "Wage Totals"
Range("A2").Formula = "=SUM(" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Wage").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Address(False, False) & ")"
```

Comment: You can sum everything and then subtract the exclusions that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link [Using SUM() in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491625/using-sum-in-vba)

You can use that idea to change your code to:

```
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastCol = Sheets("Wage").Cells(1, Sheets("Wage").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = Sheets("Wage").Cells(Sheets("Wage").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1").Value = "Wage Totals"
Range("A2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Wage").Range(Sheets("Wage").Cells(2, 3), Sheets("Wage").Cells(lastRow, lastCol)))
```

This is pretty naive solution tho becuase it assumes the usedrange limits can be found by looking for last used row on Col "A" and last used col on Row 1. You can change that method of finding the limits.

Comment: This is just giving me the value of the last row and the last column from "Wage", I need to sum the total of everything from c2 to the end of the data.

Comment: @Valborg My bad just realized my mistake, the answer is updated